# Некорректная работа сервиса при переходе на зимнее/летнее время

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

Локально развернута база Oracle и само приложение.
Время хранится в timestamp.

Нахожусь в таймзоне +01:00. 28 октября 2018 года, время 02:59:00.

Происходит запись в базу времени: 2018-10-28 02:59:00 +02:00.
Затем происходит переход на зимнее время.

Текущее время пишется уже как: 2018-10-28 02:00:00 +01:00.
В сущность заносится время в той же таймзоне и с тем же оффсетом.
И вот тут начинается самое интересное.
В базе я получаю время: 2018-10-28 02:00:00 **+02:00**.
Что за собой влечет ряд проблем.
Не совсем понимаю, каким образом происходит игнорирование перехода на зимнее время базой или hibernat'ом.

Хочется понять, на каком уровне может возникать этот дефект.
А так же, как его можно исправить.

Comment: А тип данных точно просто "TIMESTAMP" ? Или может все таки "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE". Ведь первое зону вообще не хранит

Comment: @Mike, да, все верно. TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.

Comment: должно же быть еще буквенное обозначение зоны, летние и зимние зоны различаются.

Comment: @Maxim, так полагаю, вы имеете в виду ID таймзоны. Мне стоило это уточнить, используется кастомная таймзона. Полагаю, проблема может заключаться именно в этом.
Однако проверяя таймзону на летнее/не летнее время через метод isDaylightTime, я получал корректное поведение.

Comment: Попробуйте какой нибудь SQL тулзой записать даты в летнем и зимнем периоде и опубликовать результаты запроса этих дат. Пока, два раза прочитав, так и не понял, а где же собственно дефект.